# How to draw ink continuosly on two InkCavas objects in UWP?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

Suppose you have two `InkCanvas` objects like below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <InkCanvas x:Name="Canvas1"/>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="Canvas2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Then I would like that when the user starts drawing on `Canvas1` and goes out of the bounds and then the pen input enters `Canvas2`, it starts drawing on `Canvas2`. Currently the `InkCanvas` stop drawing when the user exits its bounds and I am struggling to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, this is temporarily unavailable. Taking the pointer as an example, drawing a complete ink trace is done by pressing, dragging, and releasing with the pointer. While keeping the drag state, it moves directly to another `InkCanvas`. Since the other `InkCanvas` does not get the pointer pressed event, there is no starting point, and it will not draw ink along the pointer track.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT thank you for your response. That is exactly what I suspected. I suppose I will have to architecture my app in a different way.